# how to call a variable inside quotation marks/string in C?

Tags: c

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>
int main()
{
   int a,b,c;
   char array[10]
   print("Enter two numbers : ");
   scanf("%d %d",&a,&b);
   c=a+b;
   array[0] = "c";
   return 0;
}
```

Here I need to assign the value of c to array[0].
How can I do that?
i can be done in c# using $ sign.

e.g:

```
string filepath = "c/users/desktop/test.txt";
System.IO.File.WriteAllBytes($"{filepath}", resources.test);
```

Comment: `snprintf(array, sizeof(array), "%d", c);`?

Comment: Or if `c` must be one-digit number and want to affect only `array[0]` (not other elements of `array`), `array[0] = c - '0';`

Comment: If you want to convert an integer (`c`) to a string, use `snprintf` as MikeCAT suggested.  If you want to do something else, please explain.

Comment: Or you may want to simply assign the value of `c` to `array[0]`: `array[0] = c;`

Comment: What are you really trying to do? What is the problem you have? What, if any, output are you supposed to get from your program, and what are you actually getting? What is your assignment, complete with all requirements and limitations?

Comment: In your C# example code, the `$` is kinda unnecessary, no? I'm not familiar with C#, but it seems that `$"{filepath}"` will just create a string that is equal to `filepath`, so you don't need the interpolation. Perhaps you should pick a better example.

Comment: This makes no sense... The C# code is doing something completely different than the C code. Maybe we can help if you explain what you are trying to do in C.

Comment: Your question seems to be wrong-headed. I guess you just want to do something like `Console.WriteLine($"{a} + {b} == {c}");` I C, you wouldn't have to use a temporary string here, just use `printf("%d + %d == %d\n", a, b, c);`.

Answer (score 2):

You can't.  However, there are other solutions like `sprintf`.

Let's make it more obvious.

You're using two different data types.

```
int a, b, c;        // Each integer is 4 bytes wide
char array[10];     // Each element is 1 byte  wide
```

In case you want to save the result of `a + b` as a string, you need to have an appropriate buffer size.  For example, to save the result of `5 + 5`, you'll need at least 2 bytes of space in `array` to print `10`.  Why?  Because both numbers/position in `10`, the `1` and `0` require a byte each in an array of characters - Taking up a total of 2 bytes in `array`.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
   int a,b, c;
   char array[10];
   
   printf("Enter two number: ");
   scanf("%d %d", &a, &b);
   
   c = a + b;
   sprintf(array, "%d", c);
   printf("Result: %.*s\n", 2, array);
   return 0;
}
```

Output when 5 5:

```
10
```

However, if you run the same again but adding 100 100, the output will be:

```
20
```

... whats obvisouly not appropriate - We're missing a `0`.  The issue is because we told printf to only read 2 bytes.  We need to read at least 3 bytes to represent `200` using the char-array.

To fix this issue, you need to tell `printf` to read 3 bytes:

```
   printf("Result: %.*s\n", 3, array);
```

which now prints `200` appropriately.  This however, is not a solution for a long run.  You should take a deeper look in C to understand the basics of data types and how strings, and integers are both represented differently.